# As sun rises up in morning my enthusiasm for work decreases

Tags: sentence-construction

While conversing with someone I said this line in a hurry:

> As sun rises up in morning my enthusiasm for work decreases.

I am pretty sure that this sentence is totally wrong grammatically, I need to know how to correct it. I wanted to convey that as the morning time  progresses my enthusiasm for doing work also reduces gradually.

Comment: Why wouldn't you start the sentence with the construction you used to explain what you meant: "As the morning progresses, my enthusiasm for work gradually decreases". Why the word 'morning' needs the definite article, I'm not sure, but the sentence sounds better with it (at least to me).

Answer (score 2):

I'd say

> While the sun is rising in the morning, my enthusiasm for work decreases.

The use of 'while' and the present continuous implies that it is an ongoing process, not an instantaneous moment.

Comment: I think "as" is better than "while" here, as "as" idiomatically implies some kind of causal relationship, while "while" does not.

Answer (score 2):

The OP's sentence is quite OK grammatically with the use of the definite article before sun and morning:

As the sun rises (up) in the morning, my enthusiasm for work decreases.

You can also use the subordinate clause in the present continuous as follows:

As the sun is rising in the morning, my enthusiasm for work decreases.

Alternatively. You can use "while" in the present simple or continuous, without any difference in meaning.